# Why annotation cannot be resolved despite proper import?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I have maven project with spring dependency successfully added. Component annotation is resolved when used, but Autowired annotation generates error, despite that it appears on the build path. How do i fix this?

[image]

first component class

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Comp1 {
}
```

second component class

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
//error: The import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired cannot be resolved
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Component
public class Comp2 {
    @Autowired // error: Autowired cannot be resolved to a type
    private Comp1 comp1;

    public Comp1 getComp1() {
        return comp1;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Spr</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spr</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: When does the error happen? When building, testing, at runtime? The distinction can be important with Maven and its scoped dependencies.

Comment: Error happens before compile in eclipse.

Comment: can you check your build path, which version of java is supported

Comment: your pom.xml doesn't contain the spring-beans dependency, though It is there in the file structure.. try adding it to the pom. see what happens..

Comment: noticed you're using JRE 1.5 in your project - could be related to that

Comment: [jre1.8.0_162] does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deletion of local maven repository folder (.m2) and redownloading it, solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add these dependencies

```
</dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: these dependencies are not available in my pom file, added and error is gone

Answer (score 0):

Add Spring beans dependency, since Autowire annotation is part of spring-beans dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>your-version</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It does not help. It is automatically added with spring-context. Adding it explicitly does not solve the issue.